# Can't assign type to generic prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### Initial simplified question

Can't assign `onActivityChange` type to `onChange`:

```js
type ActivityType = { 
  id: string; 
  name: string;
}

const onChange = <TOption extends {}>(value: TOption) => {
  console.log(value);
}

const onActivityChange = (value: ActivityType) => {
  console.log(value);
}

// error
const handler: typeof onChange = onActivityChange;
```

Error:

```
Type '(value: ActivityType) => void' is not assignable to type '<TOption extends {}>(value: TOption) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'TOption' is not assignable to type 'ActivityType'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ActivityType': id, name
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN0aAKuaBeKBvKAKCikQBMAuKAZ2ACdEA7AcwG4iTGBDAWwitoMWrQgF9ChOAHtGtKDIDCACy4scUADzoA8mCQyoEAB7AIjMtXyiAfAApkXADYBXflB17EMgJRRs1-GIoaVkpRwgAOkcpZnsnV28RcUkZORl4JFRQZVVmdTiXNwyUNBBMSF9-QJIQ6jDI6NiHQsSxCVrgKBVzcLoqUEgpADN5Rhy1P1HirJBxvPYgA)

### [**edited**] My usecase, react

I'm using react:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

type ActivityType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

type DropdownProps = {
    onChange: <TOption extends {}>(value: TOption) => void;
};

const Dropdown: FC<DropdownProps> = ({ onChange }) => <div onClick={onChange}>Hello, World!</div>;

const App = () => {
    const onActivityChange = (value: ActivityType) => {
      console.log(value);
    };
    
    // error
    return <Dropdown onChange={onActivityChange} />;
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Error:

```
Type  (value: ActivityType) => void  is not assignable to type  <TOption extends {}>(value: TOption) => void 
Types of parameters  value  and  value  are incompatible.
Type  TOption  is not assignable to type  ActivityType 
Type  {}  is missing the following properties from type  ActivityType :  id, name
```

How to fix it and save type inference of `onChange` type?

Comment: You can't assign it because it's not assignable. [You could easily get runtime errors](https://tsplay.dev/mAad4m). What exactly is your use case, here? Because "fixing" this requires that we know what you're trying to do and why. Right now it's either "change the type of `onChange`" or "change the type of `handler`", and it's really not clear what you mean by "save type inference of `onChange` type". What "inference" are you talking about?

Comment: See prev comment. I mean, *maaaaybe* you're looking for [an instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) as in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wX0zDw)? But it's not clear from the question. Please [edit] to explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jcalz Added added a use case

Comment: Your use case code should be a [mre] that others can play around with where the only problem is the one you're having. Third-party or private code should be replaced.  Also, do we need to know react to answer your question? If so, please add a "react" tag. If not, please make sure to remove react references from your code.

Comment: @jcalz thanks! firstly I tried to reproduce a minimal example. With your help I understood that it wasn't enough

Comment: I don't know anything about react so I can't really help much, but... doesn't that `onClick` expect a mouse event handler and not just an arbitrary thing? It's very unclear to me what will actually happen at runtime but it kind of seems like you're hoping that a mouse event will have an `id` and a `name` property. But it doesn't, right? I guess I'll disengage since I understand even less about this code than I did to start with. Hopefully someone with react experience will step in and guide you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Generic type should have the type specified.

Update your last line to this and the error should be gone

```
const handler: typeof onChange<ActivityType> = onActivityChange;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN0aAKuaBeKBvKAKCikQBMAuKAZ2ACdEA7AcwG4iTGBDAWwitoMWrQgF9ChOAHtGtKDIDCACy4scUADzoA8mCQyoEAB7AIjMtXyiAfAApkXADYBXflB17EMgJRRs1-GIoaVkpRwgAOkcpZnsnV28RcUkZORl4JFRQZVVmdTiXNwyUNBBMSF9-QJIQ6jDI6NiHQsSxCVrgKBVzcLoqUEgpADN5Rhy1DWKssqwA3HSEEuzuvPYgA)

Comment: Yes, [that's certainly possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78054605/cant-assign-type-to-generic/78054684#comment137605149_78054605), but it's not clear from the question if that's the intent.  You should also link to the relevant docs for instantiation expressions, since this approach only makes sense since TS4.7.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch in the types of parameters between onChange and onActivityChange.
Try this

```
    type ActivityType = { 
  id: string; 
  name: string;
}

const onChange = <TOption extends {}>(value: TOption) => {
  console.log(value);
}

const onActivityChange = (value: ActivityType) => {
  console.log(value);
}

const handler: <TOption extends {}>(value: TOption) => void = onActivityChange;
```

Comment: You said "try this", but if you try it, [it doesn't work](https://tsplay.dev/m3q32w), it's exactly the same problem. Did you try it yourself before posting?